# Attribute matchers in CSS don't work with IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

We noticed on our website that the CSS was broken with IE11, while it worked fine with IE10. After a look at the CSS source, it turns out that IE11 (it seems) has dropped its support for attributes matchers: we tried on our VM, we tried on BrowserStack, and the result is that these rules...

```
img[src$='separator.png'] { display: none; }
a[href="javascript:addBookemart()"] { text-decoration: none; }
```

... do work on IE10, but not anymore on IE11. I find it hard to believe that the support for this feature would've been dropped... plus, I can't find anyone talking about such a thing over the interwebs. Might there be anything else causing this issue?

Here's a pen for testing purposes:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJNyJW

Comment: can you make a small Demo using www.jsbin.com

Comment: CanIUse shows perfect support for CSS3 selectors in IE 11:  http://caniuse.com/#search=css3%20selectors

Comment: working fine on i8 and i7

Comment: Check your `<!DOCTYPE>` and watch out for a `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />`.

Comment: Can you provide a link to your site? I'm getting curious now. And are you positive that IE11 is not running in a compatibility mode?

Comment: Works for me in Internet Explorer 11: http://i.imgur.com/gNHhlJy.png. You don't happen to have your developer tools opted-into an earlier document mode, do you?

Comment: It is opted into an earlier document mode. Don't know why though. There is no X-UA-Compatible meta entry, there is no DOCTYPE at all... here's the url: https://webline.montepaschi-banque.fr/es@b/fr/mobile/index.jsp

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, IE11 is picky about [attr="value"] having double quotes around the value.

Answer (score 1):

I found I was having this issue and it turned out that IE11 was case sensitive with the attribute values.