# Hiding disabled select options in internet explorer > 11 using angularjs

Tags: html, css, angularjs, select, drop-down-menu

I was wondering how I can hide the disabled `options` in AngularJS for IE? 
To be more clear take a look at this fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/s723gqo1/1/

I use this `css` for hiding the disabled options in chrome/firefox, but they don't work in IE:

```
select option[disabled]:first-child {
  display: none;
}
```

I have seen other questions here that suggest using JavaScript for removing the disabled option, but I couldn't get it plugged into my use case.

Any help is appreciated!

**Edit:**
I have these meta tags in my head:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

**Edit 2**
this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/20373614/4451931 is too general, and I cannot solve my problem with this answer, for I know it should be done with javascript, but my question is **How?**

Where should I put the logic for remove and add of disabled options in provided jsfiddle?

**Edit 3**
I implemented the provided answer in my project, but unfortunately, it didn't solve my problem.

the provided fiddle by this link https://jsfiddle.net/rsuuwkh9/ renders the default select option like this:
[image]

but in my project it is rendered like this:

[image]

The problem is that when the condition of showing the default option is true and it becomes false and then true again, in my project the default option disappears but in provided answer fiddle it is restored to where it should be, I would be happy if anyone helps me with this case!

Comment: take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30464405/attribute-matchers-in-css-dont-work-with-ie11

Comment: @SergChernata I provided my meta tags

Comment: SInce you are using angular you could also use ng-if or ng-show directives on the options in the html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Options with display:none not hidden in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20373558/options-with-displaynone-not-hidden-in-ie)

Comment: @JasperSeinhorst You are absolutely right, what should be the condition of `ng-if`?

Comment: Something that returns true or false. I dont know your html template and your controller.

Comment: @JasperSeinhorst My template is exactly the same as template of the jsfiddle.

Comment: @SanchitPatiyal Colud you please tell my how that question helps me in my case? I know I should use a combination of hide()/remove/detach. but my problem is that, how it is applied in the jsfiddle I provided?

Comment: @badzilla could you please reproduce your case from Edit 3 at jsfiddle?

Comment: @krutkowski86 unfortunately it is happening in my project, there is nothing special really ! I only use angular 1.5.11

Comment: @badzilla so I think you should accept the answer because we can't help you without providing us your code which doesn't work as it supposed to.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a working jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/rsuuwkh9/

```
<select ng-model="selectedName" ng-change="resetSkills()" ng-options="name as name.name for name in names">
    <option value="" ng-if="!selectedName">--Select a name --</option>
</select>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I 'll check it tomorrow to see if it really works in my project or not, anyway very neat usage of `ng-if`